# An error has occured

Tags: bug, documentation, error-message, documentation-drafts

I am receiving this error while trying to improve [draft](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/92013?draftId=77590).

[image]

Comment: You should probably add the link to the proposed change in a screenshot.

Comment: actually it's working now, though have included a link.